# How can I iterate over multiple internal links on a site to output all email addresses using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to retrieve all email addresses from [this site's](http://www.indiainfoline.com/Markets/Company/A.aspx) internal alphabetized indices.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to use BSoup to first go through all the different alphabet links, and then go through each company page to print all the respective email addresses.

I've already been able to print a list of all the companies on the site, but I'm not sure how to iterate over another level of links. I considered using a dictionary and creating keys for each letter respectively but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is the code so far which successfully pulls all company names, and a regex to individually pull email addresses one by one. How can I best print all email addresses at once?

Any input is appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
#alphabet = ['a']

resultsdict = {}
companyname = []
url1 = 'http://www.indiainfoline.com/Markets/Company/'
url2 = '.aspx'
for element in alphabet:
    html = requests.get(url1 + element + url2).text
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
    # find the links to companies
    company_menu = bs.find("div",{'style':'padding-left:5px'})
    # print all companies links
    companies = company_menu.find_all('a')
    for company in companies:
        print company.getText().strip()







import re
# example company page
html = requests.get('http://www.indiainfoline.com/Markets/Company/Adani-Power-    Ltd/533096').text
EMAIL_REGEX = re.compile("mailto:([A-Za-z0-9.\-+]+@[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4})")
re.findall(EMAIL_REGEX, html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion from someone who did a lot of web scraping jobs: make a loop with the company link, open the page and get the e-mail it finds (or any data you wish). I only saw one e-mail link at the page, so the one it finds will do. A rough example:

```
for company in companies:
    company_html = requests.get(company['href'])
    company_bs = BeautifulSoup(company_html)
    company_page_links = company_bs('a')
    for link in company_page_links:
        if link['href'].startswith('mailto:'):
            #You found the e-mail address!
            break#Exits the loop, as you already found the address
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's a great idea but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not very familiar with using loops so my syntax is probably off, but I keep getting a MissingSchema error.